# AddEventListener and webpack HRM

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-hmr

I have a little project and decided to try webpack for it.

Using [Hot reload](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html) I was able to bundle everything and update on change of js or sass.

The thing is, I have some event liteners like

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
       //do something
});
```

When I change some code inside those listeners, hot reload shows the updated code, but the binded element is the old one.

I'm using vainilla js.

Is there a way to rebind all the listeners without manually removing the event listeners?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Running into the same problem...

Comment: No, I ended up doing f5 :(